# тестирование функции с помощью jest

Tags: javascript, jest

в jest тестируя функцию MouseEvent не срабатывает
в не теста все работает хорошо
как исправить проблему подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Так ошибка вон в тех строчках, поправьте и всё будет работать!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите свой код. Что пробовали?

Comment: Я сейчас не дома а так пробовал js dom но при запросе к body все равно все показывало по нулям.